# How to find the element <li class> tag in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, find, element

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a7yv.png) how to find the list of header element

how to find the list of header element mention in screeen shot

Comment: Can you share the HTML in the form of text rather than image? Also share the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS selector: `.header__inner #mainmenulabel+ul > li`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).